# CORS blocks LinkedIn share API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cors, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I try to post new content using LinkedIn share API through JavaScript from AngularJS application as given below.

```
var xml = "<share><comment>" + content + "</comment><visibility><code>anyone</code></visibility></share>";

var req = {
   method: 'POST',
   url: 'https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares?oauth2_access_token=' + account.token,
   headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
   },
   data: xml
};

$http(req).success(function(data) {
   console.log(data);
   console.log('published to linkedin');
}).error(function() {
   console.log(arguments);
   console.log('failed to publish to linkedin');
});
```

I can successfully POST this data. However the browser blocks the response from being read because the response doesn't have an 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header.

[image: Access-Control-Allow-Origin]

But, I have given the `http://localhost:3000` and 'https://localhost:3000' domains in LinkedIn application settings.

[image: LinkedIn Application Settings]

And the request/response in Chrome looks like this.

[image: Failing request response]

Any thoughts on how to be able to read the response and not let the browser block it?

I think the problem is the missing `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the LinkedIn API response?

Comment: You should look into the JS SDK, https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/js-sdk

Comment: @ritesh: _“yes,you have to set the header”_ – he can not set that header for a service that he doesn’t have control over.

Comment: @CBroe I am using the rest api documented at https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/rest-api. Not the JS SDK.

Comment: Yeah, I got that. However, the JS SDK is provided specifically to make using their API from JavaScript easier …

Comment: @CBroe I tried using the JS SDK. But I get a `400 Bad Request`. Coming back to REST API, why doesn't LinkedIn send an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header ? Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like LinkedIn's REST API doesn't support CORS. They suggest to use REST API from the backend and not from browser. JS-SDK must be used from the browser.

https://developer-programs.linkedin.com/forum/cors