# Hitting the http get request for linkedin giving error in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-services, linkedin-api

I am doing signup with linkedin and need to fetch access code and basic profile details. But when I post the request, I am getting CORS error in my console, when I hit the URL directly in browser, it takes me to the signin page correctly. What would be the problem hitting the request?

CORS issue resolved:

I found localhost:4200 does not had '/' and after including it , CORS error was resolved , but hitting my http.get is having a problem
component:

```
  import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import {Http} from '@angular/http';
    import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
    import {map} from 'rxjs/operators'
    import { mapToExpression } from '../../../node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/render3/view/util';
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class LinkedInService {

      constructor(private http:Http) {
        console.log("In Linked in constructor");
       }

       public linkedInSignIn(){
          console.log ("Linked in Sign in");
          let authURL ="https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?"+// "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?"+
          "response_type=code"+
          "&client_id=781872"+
          "&state=xys"+
          "&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4200/";
          console.log("auth rul" +authURL);
          this.http.get(authURL).pipe(map(res => res.json()))
          .subscribe((res:Response)=>{
            console.log("Http Get " + res);
          });//people => this.people = people);
       }    

      public linkedInSignOut(){

       }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please try removing this .pipe(map(res => res.json())) and see what are you getting in response?

Comment: I get this error if I remove it Argument of type '(res: Response) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Response) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'res' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'import("f:/recipeBook/node_modules/@angular/http/src/static_response").Response' is not assignable to type 'Response'.
      Property 'redirected' is missing in type 'Response'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT :**

You need not require to `map` your response object from `http.get()`. It is automatically done by new `angular6 http`.

So it should be this way :

`this.http.get(authURL).subscribe((res:any)=> {console.log("Http Get " + res); });`

**Original answer related to `CORS` :**

As suggested in that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29512646/cors-blocks-linkedin-share-api), try to invoke `linkedIn api` from your backend api and not from the browser directly. This will solve your `Cross origin` related problem.

`Linkedin` will directly not allow any third application to execute its `api`. It has to be from your backend `api` itself and not the browser.

Comment: Hi the issue happened because of my redirecturi , I didnt given localhost:4200/ ,/ was missing , because of that I got CORS issue. But now Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Response.push../node_modules/@angular/http/fesm5/http.js.Body.json  this is error I am getting.

Comment: Ok remove `json` from line, because angular6 http automatically does that for you. So no need of `map` too now. `this.http.get(authURL).subscribe((res:Response)=>{
            console.log("Http Get " + res);
          })`

Comment: i tried above comment.I got this error message. Argument of type '(res: Response) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Response) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'res' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'import("f:/recipeBook/node_modules/@angular/http/src/static_response").Response' is not assignable to type 'Response'.
      Property 'redirected' is missing in type 'Response'.

Comment: You could add type as any, if you are not sure about its type. `this.http.get<T>(authURL).subscribe((res:any)=>{ console.log("Http Get " + res); }) `