# CORS http requests in a angular service

Tags: node.js, angular, cors, angular5, angular6

so i was wondering is it possible to send cross-domain requests in an angular services? because i have service but when i send a rquest i get the following error:

[image]

so i check the request itself :

[image]

and no cors has been enabled, then i tried adding it to the backend because that i an answer that comes up a lot but it still didnt help. so here is my code :

```
this.http.get("https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=[ID]&client_secret=[SECRET]").subscribe((data:any) => console.log(data));
```

i was wondering can you add an header to the get request ? if any more details are necessary just write a comment and i will edited in here.

**EDIT:**
my back-end

```
var app = express();
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', ['*']);
  res.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
  res.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
  next();
});
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('MONGO_URL', {  useNewUrlParser: true, promiseLibrary: require('bluebird') })
  .then(() =>  console.log('connection successful'))
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/OMRT')));
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/OMRT')));
app.use('/dashboard', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/OMRT')));
app.use('/api', apiRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.sendStatus(err.status);
});

module.exports = app;
```

i use express/node.js backend and the above snippet i used to add an header to allow the origin. i added my localhost because of the error.

**redirect-URLS:**

[image]

Comment: cross origin blocked

Comment: could you explain this further ?

Comment: Check the documentation of linkedin cros origin

Comment: so i should send the request from a javascript file, and let a angular service control this file ? because i have to get my data somehow in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not up to you to add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` it in the header, it's up to LinkedIn. So I have no idea why people tell you to change your backend headers.. If adding `Origin` to your angular request doesn't help, it means LinkedIn has blocked your origin url (localhost) or simply hasn't implemented CORS. In that case, your backend will have to do the request, so you have to add a new endpoint to your backend and let it do the request to LinkedIn. Take a look at this: [HTTP GET Request in Node.js Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577611/http-get-request-in-node-js-express)

Comment: this worked for me. but is this good practice for a angular application ?

Comment: Glad to hear! If you don't have control over the API you try to reach, there isn't any other option. And I think that for OAuth, this is the correct practice. The backend should get the access tokens.

Comment: im honest to god thankful but also triggerd at the same time. that i have to find out via stackoverflow that linkedin does not support CORS.

Comment: I don't know if it's common practice to support CORS for OAuth. I don't know enough about OAuth to be certain, but there might be security issues with letting the front-end doing everything. I'm sure they support CORS for other APIs that aren't security-related.

Comment: and i was questioning if it was common practice because of the downvote you got. i also found it weird you got that.

Answer (score -2):

**Cross-Origin Request Sharing(CORS) Request**

Read this

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/cross-origin-request-sharingcors-ashok-koritala

add header

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

Comment: where should i add this. please give a little more explaination this is really little to work with. you miss a lot of context.

Comment: Isn't it up to linkedIn to add this in their backend? What @LarsHendriks has to do is to add a `Origin` header, and hope that linkedIn accepts it.

Comment: well there are a couple of stackoverflow topics that suggest it works. like

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52179560/hitting-the-http-get-request-for-linkedin-giving-error-in-angular-2

but i don't get why i does not work for me tho.

Comment: @ShamPooSham if i am correct i allready add it in the back-end but the request just wont add in the request for some reason.

Comment: @LarsHendriks The biggest difference between the linked example and yours is that you're trying to use `client_credentials` instead of `code`.

Comment: @LarsHendriks You added it to the origin backend, not the backend you're calling (linkedIn). This will have no effect. Take a look at my other answer.

Comment: well what i am calling 'Linkedin' is the linkedin server from www.linkedin.com. im trying to setup client credential grant oauth 2.0. so i am trying to do cross-domain requests.

Comment: @KirkLarkin i just followed this guide : https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/v2/oauth2-client-credentials-flow

Comment: Yeah, I know it's the linkedIn server. What I'm saying is that if they don't accept your request there isn't much to do about it on the client side. The reason they don't accept it is probably because you're not supposed to do these calls from a browser, your backend is supposed to do the calls to linkedin oauth.

Answer (score -2):

add cors in the backend like this

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', ['*']);
    res.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    next();
});
```

Comment: also, you can add cors package [Cors](https://github.com/expressjs/cors) using this

Comment: How is his API's backend related to LinkedIn's `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`? It is LinkedIn which is not allowing requesty from his front-end

Comment: this didnt do anything for me..

i will edit some more of my backend in so you can see where i should place it in my back-end.

Comment: after adding this did you try restarting your server?

Comment: i did. but it does nothing. keep in mind i am trying to cross-domain requests. to the server my request is going to is not mine.

Comment: add cors package in nodejs using the step provided in the comments

Comment: does not work for me either.