# HTTP Response Error with Post to LinkedIn using Share API v2

Tags: api, rest, linkedin-api, angular9

I am trying to post a Share to LinkedIn using OAuth v2 - I have got authorisation correctly and have the appropriate access keys.
This code is supposed to share a link on LinkedIn, but for some reason it's not working - I'm not sure why. Can anyone help?
this is my request body:

```
{
  "distribution": {
      "linkedInDistributionTarget": {}
  },
  "owner": "urn:li:person:XXXXXX",
  "subject": "Test Share Subject",
  "text": {
      "text": "Hello !"
  }
```

And this my call API shares :

```
  publishPostLink(body : any, token : any){
this.headers = new HttpHeaders(
  {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization':'Bearer '+token, 
    'cache-control': 'no-cache', 
    'X-Restli-Protocol-Version':'2.0.0', });    
return this.http.post("https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares" , body, {headers: this.headers});}
```

I get this issue:

[I've already installed the Moesif CORS and it didn't worked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJSGg.png)

I fixed the error using this post..
[it should use REST API from the backend and not from frontend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29512646/cors-blocks-linkedin-share-api)

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials`,  and `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` are HTTP *response* headers. You don't need to send those to LinkedIn, in any case. Plus, you're putting the token on the query string and in the `Authorization` header. Surely both aren't needed. Maybe clean that up a bit and, if it still doesn't work, edit your question so we can more clearly see where the problem lies.

Comment: I edited the code but it still the same problem and the same error.

Comment: I fixed the error using this post.. [it should use REST API from the backend and not from frontend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29512646/cors-blocks-linkedin-share-api)

Comment: So, just wrong API? Maybe add that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

http://localhost is an insecure request origin so its not supportted in many cases.
Try using tunneling software like Ngork https://ngrok.com/